# Get sum form a variables that loads content dynamically (from each function)

Tags: json, sum

I'm trying to get the "sum" from a variable.
I have this code now:

```
function UpdateBuddyStat()
{
 $.getJSON('/update-buddies', function(jsonData){

   var counterjson = 0;
   var LI_list_html = '';

   $.each(jsonData, function(i,value){

   var count = counterjson++;
   var username = jsonData[i].name;
   var buddy = jsonData[i].buddyid;
   var onoff = jsonData[i].onoffstate;

   var DIV_html = username+' - ['+onoff+']<div class="FunctionBuddyBox"><span class="TagBuddy" id="TagsBuddy_'+buddy+'" data-tagbuddyid="'+buddy+'">tagit</span></div>';

   LI_list_html = LI_list_html+'<li>'+DIV_html+'</li>';
   });

   $("#ShowBuddyList ul li").remove();
   $("#ShowBuddyList ul").html(LI_list_html);  
 })
}
```

What i get is this one:

```
User1 - [1]  
User2 - [0]
User3 - [0]
User4 - [1]
User5 - [0]
```

So finally i need to sum the var "onoff". In this case the result would be 2.
I have tried many options but still have'nt luck by this.
Maybe anyone have a suggestion for me? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `sum` counter and add the `onoff` value for each item (after casting to an integer):

```
function UpdateBuddyStat()
{
 $.getJSON('/update-buddies', function(jsonData){

   var counterjson = 0;
   var LI_list_html = '';
   var sum = 0;

   $.each(jsonData, function(i,value){

   var count = counterjson++;
   var username = jsonData[i].name;
   var buddy = jsonData[i].buddyid;
   var onoff = jsonData[i].onoffstate;
   sum += parseInt(onoff, 0);

   var DIV_html = username+' - ['+onoff+']<div class="FunctionBuddyBox"><span class="TagBuddy" id="TagsBuddy_'+buddy+'" data-tagbuddyid="'+buddy+'">tagit</span></div>';

   LI_list_html = LI_list_html+'<li>'+DIV_html+'</li>';
   });

   $("#ShowBuddyList ul li").remove();
   $("#ShowBuddyList ul").html(LI_list_html);  
 })
}
```